# TCPDF don't show č,ć,ž,š,đ from mysql only blank page

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, tcpdf

i use TCPDF to show php file in PDF and it work realy fine, but when I have word with č,ć,ž,š,đ letters, I got white page...

in this case, if row[adresa] has this letters,no result in pdf page,but if has no one of letters, table show in right way.

I read lot of posts, and try everuthing,change fonts, enabling encoding, but I still have problem.

Here is my code :

```
require_once('tcpdf_include.php');

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
$pdf->SetTitle('Agencija za nekretnine');
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

// set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 048', PDF_HEADER_STRING);

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('freesans');

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->Write(0, '', '', 0, 'L', true, 0, false, false, 0);

$pdf->SetFont('freesans');

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","senzal");
// Check connection

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


$id =$_POST['ajde'];//post from my index page
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM stan where id=$id ");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {


// NON-BREAKING TABLE (nobr="true")

$tbl = <<<EOD

<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" nobr="true">
 <tr>
  <th colspan="3" align="center">Nekretnina broj: $row[id] </th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Cena:</td>
  <td>$row[cena]</td>

 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Adresa</td>
  <td>$row[adresa]</td> // this rows made a problem

 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>3-1</td>
  <td>3-2</td>
  <td>3-3</td>
 </tr>
</table>
EOD;
}
$pdf->writeHTML($tbl, true, false, false, false, '');

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('example_048.pdf', 'I');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This for php code :

```
$html. ='<tr>
  <td>'.$row['cena'] .'</td>
  <td>'.$row['adresa'] .'</td>
 </tr>';
```

Comment: Hi and tnx :) problem is to show php values in html,because, if I remove <<<EOD, dont work in any case, and inside EOD  tag,we don't need ' for html...

Comment: this work,but not for letter that I write in title:                  <table class="table table-hover" width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="6" >
                                     
  <tr>
    <td>Cena</td>
    <td>' . $row['cena'].  '</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Adresa</td>
    <td>' . $row['adresa'].  '</td>
  </tr>
</table>

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
$html = '                           <table class="table table-hover" width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="6" >
                                      <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                          <th>title1</th>
                                          <th>title2</th>
                                          <th>title3</th>
                                          <th>title4</th>
                                          <th>title4</th>
                                          <th>title5</th>
                                          </tr>
                                      </thead>
                                      </table>';


    // Print text using writeHTMLCell()
    $pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);
```