# TCPDF show ? instead of Č

Tags: tcpdf

I have problem with TCPDF to show on PDF page my UTF-8 data. Here is part of my code :

TCPDF work fine, but when create Pdf I get ?a?anska insted Čačanska.

I try with "SET NAMES 'utf8'" ,but no result.. If I remove utf8_encode, get blank page.

I try to use this answer, but no help: 
[Why cant I use č,ć,đ charters in TCPDF table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685964/why-cant-i-use-c-c-d-charters-in-tcpdf-table)

and my old question:
[TCPDF don't show č,ć,ž,š,đ from mysql only blank page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20772647/tcpdf-dont-show-c-c-z-s-d-from-mysql-only-blank-page)

```
Font:

    $pdf->SetFont('freeserif', '', 14, '', true);

Create Pdf:

    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

Part od code :

    $id =$_POST['ajde']; // get data from jqgrid
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM kuca where id=$id ");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
       {

    $u= $row['adresa'];

     $html = '

  <table width="540" height="339" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="2" class="table table-hover" >  
<tr> 
    <td><div align="left">Adresa:</div></td>
    <td style="font-family:freesans" ">' . $u. '</td>
</tr>

</table>

    $pdf->writeHTML(utf8_encode($html), true, 0, true, 0);
```

Tnx,

Pavle

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you still need to know this, but I already explained it in one of my answers, but you need to encode you content to utf-8 again (and utf-8 already encoded, remains utf-8 in PHP) and convert it to HTML_ENTITIES. I may explained it a bit weird, so people can correct me on that : )

In short:

```
$your_new_content = mb_convert_encoding(utf8_encode($your_content), 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
```

Oh, a reminder that this fix will mess up your regular echoes, but it will turn out well in TCPDF. This fix can be used on various things, so I hope this helps.